# How can I use str_replace with array for multiple items?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, str-replace

I have this code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->Load('/home/dom/public_html/cache/feed.xml');
    $xmlor = '/home/dom/public_html/cache/feed.xml';

    // open file and prepare mods
    $fh = fopen($xmlor, 'r+');
    $data = fread($fh, filesize($xmlor));
    $dmca_claim_jpg = array( 'baduser_.jpg','user78.jpg' );
    $dmca_claim_link = array( 'mydomain.com/baduser_','mydomain.com/user78' );
    echo "Opening local XML for edit..." . PHP_EOL;
    $new_data = str_replace("extdomain.com", "mydomain.com", $data);
    $new_data2 = str_replace($dmca_claim_jpg, "DMCA.jpg", $data);
    $new_data3 = str_replace($dmca_claim_link, "#", $data);
    fclose($fh);

    // run mods
    $fh = fopen($xmlor, 'r+');
    fwrite($fh, $new_data);
    fwrite($fh, $new_data2);
    fwrite($fh, $new_data3);
    echo "Updated feed URL and DMCA claims in local XML..." . PHP_EOL;
    fclose($fh);
```

It does not give any errors when executing but messes up the xml file  by removing the first two lines (weird) when fwriting `$new_data2` and `$new_data3` to xml file.

It works fine writing only `$new_data`...

I think it has to do with the `$dmca_claim_jpg/link` arrays.

Comment: Could it be an issue with `$dmca_claim_jpg` and `$dmca_claim_link`?

Comment: Yes, i believe it is. I just can't seem to get it fixed

Comment: Can you put a sample of your xml?

Comment: Do you really want 3 copies of the XML in the resulting file, with different replacements in each one?

Comment: You should use `fopen` mode `r` if you're just reading from the file, and `w` if you're overwriting the file. Why are you using `r+` in both cases?

Comment: I dont want 3 copies...I believe it's writing three times...as for the fopen and fwrite modes, it works both ways, I changed it as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Parse XML using SimpleXML or DOMDocument it's cleaner and you have a standard OOP way of accessing nodes

Comment: Sorry, I do have it, just forgot to paste it. I just edited the code and added. Thank you.